# How to fetch data from two tables by the reference in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch data from two firebase table. Both tables are having some reference connected, but I am not able to find relative data according to reference.

Here are images of my table:

[this is first table with some reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PYyg.png)

[this is second table having first table reference in this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNKYa.png)

Could anyone please help me how can I fetch data
(i am using `nodejs`)?

this is first table

```
 "10a" : {  "id" : "10a","location" : {
"lat" : 24.909546,
"lng" : 67.049336},"place_name" : "liaquatabad 10 number"},
```

this is second table

```
"-L6peGaR-wbL4dO4jfby" : {
  "adda_ref" : "10a",
  "email" : "",
  "first_name" : "asdfasd",
  "id" : "-L6peGaR-wbL4dO4jfby",
  "last_name" : "",
  "mob_no" : "234234234",
  "password" : "asdas23234",
  "status" : 1,
  "type" : "driver",
  "vehicle" : "Suzuki"
},
```

i need all details from user table and only need place_name from the second table

i did try this code

```
created: function () {
let self = this;

const db = firebase.database();
self.userRef = db.ref('/users');
self.userRef.orderByChild('type').equalTo('driver').on('value', function(snap){
    let renderData = snap.val();
    self.data1 = [];
    if(renderData !== null) {
        let renderDataKeys = Object.keys(renderData);
        let process_item = 0;
        let grabData = [];
        renderDataKeys.forEach(function (val) {
            let item = renderData[val];
            item['key'] = val;
            item['time'] = "";
            if (val.length === 20) {
                item['time'] = func.set_date_ser(new Date(func.decode_key(val)));
            } else if (item.hasOwnProperty("createdAt")) {
                item['time'] = moment(item.createdAt).format("hh:mm A DD/MM/YYYY");
            }
            grabData.push(item);
            process_item++;
            if (process_item === renderDataKeys.length) {
                self.data1 = grabData;
                self.dataLoad = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

},

Comment: You've included two links to pictures of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace these with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It would also be great if you show the code of what you've already tried.